# Flutter Launcher: Go back to the HomeScreen when Home Button is pressed

Tags: android, flutter, launcher, android-launcher

I am trying to make a launcher using flutter. I have made multiple screens for doing specific tasks like HomeScreen. AppDrawerScreen and so on. The problem I am facing is whenever I go to say AppDrawerScreen and press on the Home Button, I am not redirected to the HomeScreen. How can I handle this scenario?

Comment: You probably need to write some native Android code to override `Activity.onNewIntent()` in your main launcher activity. If your launcher is already in front, it will not be recreated when HOME is pressed a second time. Hopefully that gives you a direction to investigate, but I don't know the flutter way to do this.

Comment: https://github.com/igaurab/button_press

I had made a plugin just for that after searching for this answer on stack overflow. Thank you all for your comments and time. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I guess the only solution is to listen to the Home button, and there go to the first screen. there is a plugin called [hardware_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons), and about the Back button you can use the WillPopScope() widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixing to your `StatefulWidget` class.
And then you can invoke `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` method where you can listen to the `AppLifeCycleState` changes like :

1. inactive
2. paused
3. resume and soon

But in your case since you want to navigate to `HomeScreen` when Android `Home Button` is pressed so you need to check if `AppLifeCycleState.inactive` is `true` (which means you have pressed the Android `Home Button` and app is running in background) and there you can add your code to Navigate to `HomeScreen`.

Also you can refer to this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) for more information.